# Use begin and rescue in select syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to select the `task` which won't get exception in the  following code,
How could I get it ?

if the task status contains the pid and the process is running on my system,
then it won't get exception.

This code is in my helper function, should I move some function to Model ? (I'm using ROR)

```
  def sanitize_running_tasks(tasks)

    sanitized_tasks = tasks.select do |task|
      begin
        Process.kill 0, task.status.to_i
      rescue Exception => e
        task.status = :FAIL
        task.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider putting the `kill` method on Task.

```
  def sanitize_running_tasks(tasks)
    tasks.select &:kill
  end

  class Task
    def kill
      Process.kill 0, status.to_i
      true
    rescue Exception => e
      mark_failed!
      false
    end

    def mark_failed!
      update_attributes status: :FAIL
    end
  end
```

Comment: @poc the answer really depends on the scope of your domain problem.  I do prefer logic in the model over the controller for smaller applications.  That said, most of the time I write "Use Case" or "Service" object that perform the logic and keep my controllers and models simple.